# Walking between Wi-Fi access points causes network to be disabled

Tags: 2.2-froyo, wi-fi, motorola-triumph

Testing my new Motorola Triumph the last couple of days, I've noticed issues with the Wi-Fi.

Aside from connection attempts to the 802.1x EAP network at school causing reboots (a known problem with the Triumph's software and/or wireless chipset), I've run into a problem where if I walk between buildings, it won't reconnect automatically. When I go into the Wi-Fi settings, the network is "Disabled", presumably because there were issues reconnecting while I was outside on the sidewalk.

My LG Optimus V never had this problem; I used it all semester and it always reconnected within a minute or two of settling into a new room. It occasionally disabled the network, but I can count those occurrences on one hand (in decimal ;-). The Triumph did it half a dozen times in one day. (I change buildings a lot.)

Is this something that can be fixed? Perhaps by rooting and tweaking some system settings file(s)? If I can work out most of the software issues by tweaking the phone myself, I'll live with the few that will undoubtedly be unfixable without an update from Motorola.

Meanwhile I've tested with the insecure campus network. The unauthenticated network reconnected within 30 seconds of my entering a new building. (How fortunate that IT maintains a network that dumb devices can use for Internet access.)

*(Note: I have no desire to use a custom ROM unless it fully supports **all** the features of the phone. That includes HDMI output and the ability to have Wi-Fi & Bluetooth turned on simultaneously without pegging the CPU. Unfortunately that lets out ever using CM7 unless those known issues are fixed.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug related to the underlying issues with 802.1x EAP authentication in the Motorola Triumph's software / Wi-Fi firmware or wherever the bug is that causes the reboots I mentioned in my original question.

Short answer: Don't use 802.1x EAP networks. They will cause problems with the Triumph.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your WiFi sleep settings.  While I don't know specifically how Motorola works, if it's anything like Samsung, if you hit the menu button and go to

`Settings -> Wireless and Network -> Wi-Fi settings`

then hit your Menu button and select

`Wi-Fi sleep policy.`

If it isn't on the setting already, change it to

`When screen turns off`.

What I have found is that when I have my sleep policy set to "Never", I have issues when I get home from work.  It's almost like the Wi-Fi doesn't know that it should look for a new network, but whenever the Wi-Fi sleeps and comes back up, it will find the network.

Comment: What that change does is essentially turn the Wi-Fi off whenever the screen is off, letting the phone switch back to (more power-intensive) 3G while you're not using it. Battery life on my old LG Optimus V was much shorter when I let it turn the Wi-Fi off, and Wi-Fi sleep was one of the first things I told my new Triumph NOT to do. This also doesn't happen on the unencrypted network I use now.

Comment: @dgw, This is good to know.  I may change mine back based on my not so great battery life.  Hopefully I don't see the problem of not picking up my home network when I get home.

Comment: it's definitely a driver thing. If your phone has the issue, then it has a bug. It so happens that my phone can't handle the network that had problems anyway, but if yours can it'll be a definite trade-off. :-/